# Applying tidyr to separate only specific rows by specifying which rows to exclude

Tags: r, tidyr

I would like to separate a column by a condition that excludes certain rows. This is a minor variation on this question: [Applying tidyr separate only to specific rows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41506310/1036500) But instead of specifying which rows to separate, I'd like to specify which rows to exclude from separating.

For example, lets say we want to split all rows of the 'text' column, *except* for the ones that have `here_do` in them:

```
#creating DF for the example
df <- data.frame(var_a = letters[1:5],
                var_b = c(sample(1:100, 5)),
                text = c("foo_bla", 
                         "here_do",
                         "oh_yes",
                         "ba_a",
                         "lan_d"))
```

I guess there would be some way of using `extract` as we see in the related question, but I can't seem to figure out how to modify the `"(here)_(do)"` part to make it work:

```
library(tidyr)
extract(df, text, into = c("first", "sec"), "(here)_(do)", remove = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind using "data.table" instead, you can try:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[!text %in% "here_do", c("first", "second") := tstrsplit(text, "_")][]
#    var_a var_b    text first second
# 1:     a    40 foo_bla   foo    bla
# 2:     b     4 here_do    NA     NA
# 3:     c    12  oh_yes    oh    yes
# 4:     d    35    ba_a    ba      a
# 5:     e    11   lan_d   lan      d
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to `separate` everything then "unseparate" the rows you wanted to exlude.

```
library('tidyverse')

df <- data.frame(var_a = letters[1:5],
                var_b = c(sample(1:100, 5)),
                text = c("foo_bla", 
                         "here_do",
                         "oh_yes",
                         "ba_a",
                         "lan_d"),
                stringsAsFactors = F)

df %>%
  separate(text, c('first_val', 'second_val'), remove = F) %>%
  mutate(
    first_val = ifelse(text == 'here_do', text, first_val),
    second_val = ifelse(text == 'here_do', NA, first_val))
#>   var_a var_b    text first_val second_val
#> 1     a    45 foo_bla       foo        foo
#> 2     b    43 here_do   here_do       <NA>
#> 3     c    81  oh_yes        oh         oh
#> 4     d    33    ba_a        ba         ba
#> 5     e    15   lan_d       lan        lan
```

Answer (score 1):

We can filter out the row that you do not want to separate, separate the rest of the rows, and then join the result back to the original data frame.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2 <- df %>%
  filter(!(text %in% "here_do")) %>%
  separate(text, into = c("First", "Second"), remove = FALSE) %>%
  right_join(df, by = c("var_a", "var_b", "text"))
df2
#   var_a var_b    text First Second
# 1     a    19 foo_bla   foo    bla
# 2     b    90 here_do  <NA>   <NA>
# 3     c    21  oh_yes    oh    yes
# 4     d     6    ba_a    ba      a
# 5     e    15   lan_d   lan      d
```

**DATA**

```
set.seed(244)

df <- data.frame(var_a = letters[1:5],
                 var_b = c(sample(1:100, 5)),
                 text = c("foo_bla", 
                          "here_do",
                          "oh_yes",
                          "ba_a",
                          "lan_d"))
```

Comment: Yes, I'm most curious to know if it can be done more simply with `extract`